# Logrotate ignoring log file without suffix?

Tags: logs, logrotate

My problem is simple. I have 5 log files in a folder, like this: `software1.txt`, `software2.txt`, etc. My Logrotate script, as follows, runs daily:

```
/var/ftp/logs/*.txt {
  daily
  rotate 36500
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    (restart services)
  endscript
}
```

This is the log I get when I run `logrotate` with the `-d` and `-f` option.

```
renaming /var/ftp/logs/apcupsd.txt.3 to /var/ftp/logs/apcupsd.txt.4 (rotatecount 36500, logstart 1, i 3),
renaming /var/ftp/logs/apcupsd.txt.2 to /var/ftp/logs/apcupsd.txt.3 (rotatecount 36500, logstart 1, i 2),
renaming /var/ftp/logs/apcupsd.txt.1 to /var/ftp/logs/apcupsd.txt.2 (rotatecount 36500, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /var/ftp/logs/apcupsd.txt.0 to /var/ftp/logs/apcupsd.txt.1 (rotatecount 36500, logstart 1, i 0),
log /var/ftp/logs/apcupsd.txt.36501 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
rotating log /var/ftp/logs/auth.txt, log->rotateCount is 36500
```

As can be seen, it ignores the actual `apcupsd.txt` file, and only rotates the logs already rotated (so `apcupsd.txt.0` does change to `apcupsd.txt.1`). I have never seen anything like this, and the strangest thing is it was working fine just a few weeks ago.

What could cause this?

Comment: Can we see the `ls -l` output of the `/var/ftp/logs/`.

Comment: Pastebin here: [here](https://pastebin.com/g4qJ4SNZ)